# Efficiency of appending to vectors

Tags: performance, scala, vector, clojure, immutability

Appending an element onto a million-element `ArrayList` has the cost of setting one reference now, and copying one reference in the future when the `ArrayList` must be resized.

As I understand it, appending an element onto a million-element `PersistenVector` must create a new path, which consists of 4 arrays of size 32. Which means more than 120 references have to be touched.

How does Clojure manage to keep the vector overhead to "2.5 times worse" or "4 times  worse" (as opposed to "60 times worse"), which has been claimed in several Clojure videos I have seen recently? Has it something to do with caching or locality of reference or something I am not aware of?

Or is it somehow possible to build a vector internally with mutation and then turn it immutable before revealing it to the outside world?

I have tagged the question [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) as well, since `scala.collection.immutable.vector` is basically the same thing, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clojure's PersistentVector's have special tail buffer to enable efficient operation at the end of the vector. Only after this 32-element array is filled is it added to the rest of the tree. This keeps the amortized cost low. [Here](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/02/01/understanding-clojures-persistentvector-implementation) is one article on the implementation. The [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) is also worth a read.

Regarding, "is it somehow possible to build a vector internally with mutation and then turn it immutable before revealing it to the outside world?", yes! These are known as [transients](http://clojure.org/transients) in Clojure, and are used for efficient batch changes.

Comment: Since the question includes numbers, it's possibly worth mentioning explicitly that the Clojure vector is a *tree* of 32 bit pointers, each level of which accounts for five bits of index. So the tree can only be five or six levels deep.

Comment: Does it mean that prepend to Clojure's vector is slower than append?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Yes, adding to the end is a constant time operation. Adding to the beginning is linear. However, if you don't need the result to be a vector (or at least not right away), you can use lazy concatenation (or another data structure).

Answer (score 7):

Cannot tell about Clojure, but I can give some comments about Scala Vectors.

Persistent Scala vectors (`scala.collection.immutable.Vector`s) are **much** slower than an array buffer when it comes to appending. In fact, they are 10x slower than the `List` prepend operation. They are 2x slower than appending to Conc-trees, which we use in Parallel Collections.

But, Scala also has **mutable** vectors -- they're hidden in the class `VectorBuilder`. Appending to mutable vectors does not preserve the previous version of the vector, but mutates it in place by keeping the pointer to the rightmost leaf in the vector. So, yes -- keeping the vector mutable internally, and than returning an immutable reference is exactly what's done in Scala collections.

The `VectorBuilder` is slightly faster than the `ArrayBuffer`, because it needs to allocate its arrays only once, whereas `ArrayBuffer` needs to do it twice on average (because of growing). `Conc.Buffer`s, which we use as parallel array combiners, are twice as fast compared to `VectorBuilder`s.

Benchmarks are here. None of the benchmarks involve any boxing, they work with reference objects to avoid any bias:

- [comparison of Scala `List`, `Vector` and `Conc`](http://chara.epfl.ch/~prokopec/npc-i7/report/#config=%7B%22filterConfig%22%3A%7B%22curves%22%3A%5B%22-1%22%2C%220%22%2C%221%22%2C%222%22%5D%2C%22order%22%3A%5B%22param-size%22%2C%22param-par%22%2C%22date%22%5D%2C%22filters%22%3A%5B%5B%22100000%22%2C%22300000%22%2C%22500000%22%2C%22900000%22%2C%221000000%22%2C%221500000%22%2C%223000000%22%2C%225000000%22%2C%229000000%22%2C%2210000000%22%2C%2215000000%22%2C%2230000000%22%2C%2250000000%22%2C%2290000000%22%2C%22150000000%22%5D%2C%5B%221%22%5D%2C%5B%221371218791000%22%5D%5D%7D%2C%22chartConfig%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A0%2C%22showCI%22%3Afalse%7D%7D)
- [comparison of Scala `ArrayBuffer`, `VectorBuilder` and `Conc.Buffer`](http://chara.epfl.ch/~prokopec/npc-i7/report/#config=%7B%22filterConfig%22%3A%7B%22curves%22%3A%5B%22-1%22%2C%223%22%2C%224%22%2C%225%22%5D%2C%22order%22%3A%5B%22param-size%22%2C%22param-par%22%2C%22date%22%5D%2C%22filters%22%3A%5B%5B%22100000%22%2C%22300000%22%2C%22500000%22%2C%22900000%22%2C%221000000%22%2C%221500000%22%2C%223000000%22%2C%225000000%22%2C%229000000%22%2C%2210000000%22%2C%2215000000%22%2C%2230000000%22%2C%2250000000%22%2C%2290000000%22%2C%22150000000%22%5D%2C%5B%221%22%5D%2C%5B%221371218791000%22%5D%5D%7D%2C%22chartConfig%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A0%2C%22showCI%22%3Afalse%7D%7D)

More collections benchmarks [here](http://scala-blitz.github.io/home/documentation//performance.html).

These tests were executed using [ScalaMeter](http://scalameter.github.io).

Comment: I'm surprised you say append is a magnitude slower. Looking at the [official table](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html), they are touted as 'eC' - effectively constant, aka O(log32N)... How is that a magnitude?

Comment: Well, it's not my personal claim, I'm just showing the benchmarks :). A 'magnitude slower' in this case comes from the constant factor of the vector-append operation, not it's algorithmic complexity. For example, an `O(n^2)` operation can be much faster than an `O(n)` operation for some range of `n`. Similarly, different `O(1)` running-time operations can have very different absolute running time.

Comment: There is no contradiction between vector-append being both constant time and an order of magnitude slower than list-prepend.

Comment: @dfan "An order of magnitude slower" simply mean "10 times slower", right? :)

Comment: Why aren't `Conc` and `Conc.Buffer` exposed to the outside world?

Comment: Because they're new - I added them to the Reactive Collections API a month or two ago. They might end up in the stdlib at some point, but the current trend is to reduce and modularize the Scala stdlib. You can still download them through Maven to use them in your projects. Both regular releases and snapshots regularly are published -- instructions are here: http://reactive-collections.com/download/ (bonus -- these guys are specialized, and do not suffer from primitive type boxing!)

Comment: For the entire API: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.storm-enroute" %% "reactive-collections-core" % "0.4")`; for just the core specialized collection classes: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.storm-enroute" %% "reactive-collections-core" % "0.4")`

Comment: @fredoverflow: Yes. In fact, if one operation is consistently an order of magnitude slower than the other (across a wide range of sizes--specifically as the size approaches infinity) then that shows the two operations have the same big-O complexity.